# Графики в ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, chart.js

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь сделать график, при этом данные брались бы с модели (дата и кол-во очков), которая была создана по принципу CodeFirst.

Вот модель

```
    using System;

namespace PersonalArea.DAL.Models
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string PatientId { get; set; }

        public string GameName { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateExit { get; set; }

        public string DifficultLevel { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вот контроллер

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            List<IGrouping<string, Result>> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList();
            ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
            return View(results);
        }
```

Вот сама вьюха, где я хочу видеть графики

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var test = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.test);
            var datapoints = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
                datapoints.push({ y: test[i].Score, x: test[i].ID, label: test[i].GameName });
            }
window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "theme2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
                },
                subtitles: [
                    { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
                ],
                data: [
                {
                        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: datapoints
                    /*[
                    { x: 10, y: 71 },
                    { x: 20, y: 55 },
                    { x: 30, y: 50 },
                    { x: 40, y: 65 },
                    { x: 50, y: 95 },
                    { x: 60, y: 68 },
                    { x: 70, y: 28 },
                    { x: 80, y: 34 },
                    { x: 90, y: 14 }
                    ]*/
                                        //Uncomment below line to add data coming from the controller.
                    //dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        };

        }
```

Но система выкидывает ошибку

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result'. Path '[0][0].patient.results'.

И ссылается на строку в контроллере

```
ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

Скажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема и как это можно решить?

Comment: Работайте с моделью. Избегайте ViewBag. Вы передаете в представление полученные данные `return View(results)`. Сделайте строго типизированное представление которое будет принимать модель `@model List<Group<string, Result>>` и работайте с моделью `@Model`

Answer (score 0):

Я как понимаю, дело в том, что мой класс не может экспортироваться в Json. Может ли быть из-за того, что класс, который компилируется в другом классе является ссылкой. Ведь каждый результат прекреплён с пациенту.